# How to read all text from folder and save txt file with same name as image jpg file in other folder python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, text-files, glob

I have ground-truth text files in the folder my file name is

```
Doc0006.Row1City.gt.txt
```

While I have image file names that have the same ground truth file **Doc0006.Row1City.gt**

```
Doc0006.Row1City0_rotate.jpg
Doc0006.Row1City1_rotate.jpg
Doc0006.Row1City2_rotate,jpg
Doc0006.Row1City3_rotate.jpg
Doc0006.Row1City4_rotate.jpg
```

I want to save the same ground truth file for all images with there original names in another folder
How can I proceed using python

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do something like the following. I have not tried the code since i dont have access to your files but you can change or adjust the code based on your need

```py
import os
import shutil
ground_truth_folder_path = '' # add your folder path here
images_folder_path = '' # add your images path
new_folder_path = '' # the new folder with the files sorted
all_ground_truth_files = os.listdir(ground_truth_folder_path)
all_images_files = os.listdir(images_folder_path)
ground_truth_images = {}
for file in all_ground_truth_files:
    ground_truth_images[file.replace(".gt.txt","")] = []

for file in all_images_files:
    ground_truth_images[file[:16]].append(file)

for key, values in ground_truth_images.items():
    new_folder_path_key = os.path.join(new_folder_path, key)
    os.mkdir(new_folder_path_key)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(ground_truth_folder_path ,key+'.gt.txt'), os.path.join(new_file_path)
    for file_name in values:
        old_file_path = os.path.join(images_folder_path ,file_name)
        new_file_path = os.path.join(new_folder_path_key, file_name)
        shutil.copy(old_file_path , new_file_path)
```

Comment: I image in one folder and ground truth.txt file in another folder, I can share images here the code is not working ``` NameError: name 'ground_truth' is not defined ```

Comment: I have edited the answer, but keep in mind i have not tested the code. I suggest you to try to understand the code and change it to make it work. learning a new language can seem hard at the start but at the end it is a language that can be understood.

Comment: Thanks i am getting error KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0560e30d29e3> in <module>
     11 
     12 for file in all_images_files:
---> 13     ground_truth_images[file[:16]].append(file)
     14 
     15 for key, values in ground_truth_images.items():

KeyError: 'Doc0006.Row1City'